# Process file contents sequentially

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, filereader, synchronous

Hi I have several files that need to be read in a specific order.

To do this, I tried to implement file reads that spawned off the `onloadend` function of the previous file.

My MWE is here: https://jsfiddle.net/q3h49dL2/

With the following test code:

```
class Chain {
  // File Chain ops
  addReadJob(job) {
    console.log("Queuing:", job.file.name);

    if (this.firstjob === undefined) {
      this.firstjob = 0;
    }

    // Store previous job 
    var lastjob = this.firstjob;

    // Create new job that passes the previous job
    // as a readbeforefunc argument to new job.
    this.firstjob = function() {
      Task.readFile(job.file, job.task, lastjob);
    }
  }

  constructor() {
    //Let's create a bunch of jobs
    var job1 = {
      file: {name: "File1",text: "File1 contents"},
      task: Task.taskDoer1
    };
    var job2 = {
      file: {name: "File2",text: "File2 contents"},
      task: Task.taskDoer2
    };
    var job3 = {
      file: {name: "File3",text: "File3 contents"},
      task: Task.taskDoer1
    };

    // Now queue them
    this.addReadJob(job1);
    this.addReadJob(job2);
    this.addReadJob(job3);

    // And process them all from the first chain
    this.firstjob();
  }
}


class Task {
  static taskDoer1(text) {console.log("randomtask:", text);}
  static taskDoer2(text) {console.log("anotherrandomtask", text);}

  // !!!HERE PROBLEMS OCCUR!!!
  static readFile(file, callback, runbeforefunc = 0) {
    var fr = new FileReadPretend();

    fr.onloadend = function(text) {
      // Run previous job in chain first
      if (runbeforefunc !== 0) {
          runbeforefunc();
      }
      callback(text);
    }
    fr.readAsText(file);
  }
}


class FileReadPretend {
  constructor(){
     this.onloadend = null;
  }
  readAsText(file) {  
    var that = this;

    setTimeout(function() {
      that.onloadend(file.text);
      console.log("--read", file.name);
    }, 1000);
  }
}


new Chain();
```

The general idea is that I queue a bunch of files and their filehandler task functions into linked queue.

Each queue then hooks the previous job in the queue into the `runBeforeFunc` in `Task.readFile` which executes before the current file is handled.

This does not seem to work however, and regardless of whether I move the `runbeforeFunc` before or after the `callback(text)` statement in the `Task.readFile` function, it still executes the jobs in the wrong order.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit trivial answer, but why don't you just change the order, like;

```
 // Now queue them
    this.addReadJob(job3);
    this.addReadJob(job2);
    this.addReadJob(job1);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4Lv10zk1/

Comment: Ha, yeah but let's just say I'd have to rewrite the whole scheduler that  queues the jobs. Is there a way to do this just by modifying `Task.readFile` or `(Chain).addReadJob` and keeping the current queue order?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, trivial practically:

```
addReadJob(job) {
   console.log("Queuing:", job.file.name);

   if (this.firstjob === undefined) {
       this.firstjob = function(){}; // dummy func
   }

   // Store previous job 
   var lastjob = this.firstjob;

   // Create new job that passes the previous job
   this.firstjob = function() {
        lastjob(); // <--- run lastjob first, duh!
        Task.readFile(job.file, job.task);
   }
}
```